# Pointing a vector to an array

Tags: c++

I'm not sure if my title is worded properly so I will elaborate here.

What I need to do is have my vector take the information from a previously built Array, shuffle it, then spit it back out. What I figured I could do because I have a for loop in place to display the information of the deck is have the vector within the main function, however at the same time I have a feeling I need to create a separate function. However, I'm not sure what method would be most efficient.
What I have thus far is this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "prototypes.h"

using std::string;
using std::endl;
using std::cout;

const string CARDS[] =
{
"2C", "3C", "4C", "5C", "6C", "7C", "8C", "9C", "TC", "JC", "QC", "KC", "AC",
"2D", "3D", "4D", "5D", "6D", "7D", "8D", "9D", "TD", "JD", "QD", "KD", "AD",
"2H", "3H", "4H", "5H", "6H", "7H", "8H", "9H", "TH", "JH", "QH", "KH", "AH",
"2S", "3S", "4S", "5S", "6S", "7S", "8S", "9S", "TS", "JS", "QS", "KS", "AS"
};

unsigned const DECK_SIZE = sizeof(CARDS) / sizeof(string);

int const SHUFFLE_COMMAND = 1;
int const SHOW_COMMAND = 2;
int const QUIT_COMMAND = 3;
const char MENU[] = "\nShowing Cards Program:\n1 -- Shuffle Cards\n2 -- Show Deck\n3 -- Quit\n: ";
const char IM_OUTTA_HERE[] =  "Buh-bye!";


int main()
{
   int command = 0;
   do
   {
    command = askForInt(MENU, QUIT_COMMAND, SHUFFLE_COMMAND);

    switch(command)
    {
        case SHUFFLE_COMMAND:

          break;
            case SHOW_COMMAND:
            for(int i = 0; i < DECK_SIZE; i++)
            {
                cout << CARDS[i] << " ";
                if(i == 12 || i == 25 || i == 38)
                    {
                        cout << endl;
                    }
            }
          break;
        case QUIT_COMMAND:
          break;    
    }
   }while(command != QUIT_COMMAND);

    cout << IM_OUTTA_HERE << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

askForInt is in another file called Functions, all it does is receive the users input (1, 2 or 3)

**EDIT:** It also must be noted that I need to do this using pointers, as this is what I'm currently trying to learn.

Comment: Why do you mix `const char` and `const string`?

Comment: So.. [`std::copy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) and [`std::random_shuffle()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) ?

Comment: What I am unsure of is how to implement those basically from within a vector, I've only been doing C++ for two weeks now

Comment: Are you required to actually reference the CARDS array contents in your shuffled implementation? or is a *copy* of that array, then shuffled and displayed, sufficient? The latter is trivial; the former, a little more complex. Keeping the original array in the original order can be done either way.

Comment: The goal is to store the array's contents into the vector (I assume a copy would suffice) and then if the user chooses so, shuffle the cards within the vector, and then wait for user input on whether or not they want the cards to be displayed.

Comment: I've posted a sample that stores the *addresses* of each `string` in the CARDS array in a vector, then shuffles those, per your edit that pointers be used for all this. It is trivial to do this with copying (in fact, literally only a few lines of code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you added the restriction this must all be done with pointers, that changes things considerably. I wrote the code below to be compatible back to C++98. Hopefully get something out of it.

Note: this is just the deck randomization portion of your goal. the rest is up to you, but has been stripped from the sample below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

const string CARDS[] =
{
    "2C", "3C", "4C", "5C", "6C", "7C", "8C", "9C", "TC", "JC", "QC", "KC", "AC",
    "2D", "3D", "4D", "5D", "6D", "7D", "8D", "9D", "TD", "JD", "QD", "KD", "AD",
    "2H", "3H", "4H", "5H", "6H", "7H", "8H", "9H", "TH", "JH", "QH", "KH", "AH",
    "2S", "3S", "4S", "5S", "6S", "7S", "8S", "9S", "TS", "JS", "QS", "KS", "AS"
};
unsigned const DECK_SIZE = sizeof(CARDS) / sizeof(string);

int main()
{
    // seed rng
    srand((unsigned)time(nullptr));

    // create a vector of const string ptrs. using pointer enumeration through the
    //  array, add the address of each string object to our deck.
    vector<const string*> deck;
    for (const string* p = CARDS; p != (CARDS + DECK_SIZE); ++p)
        deck.push_back(p);

    // shuffle the pointer vector
    random_shuffle(deck.begin(), deck.end());

    // display each deck through dereferencing.
    for (vector<const string*>::const_iterator it=deck.cbegin(); it!= deck.cend(); ++it)
        cout << (*it)->c_str() << ' ';
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
4H TS 9S TH JC AH QS 5S 8S 2D QH 9C 2C 8C 2S JS 9H JH KC 7S 4D 9D KS QC 4S AS 3S 5C KH 7D KD 3D 8D TD 3H 2H 5D JD 8H AC 4C 6S 7C 3C 6H 5H TC 6C QD 6D 7H AD
```

---

If copying is a viable option, then the following, which requires C++11 or later compliance, makes that job trivial:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

const string CARDS[] =
{
    "2C", "3C", "4C", "5C", "6C", "7C", "8C", "9C", "TC", "JC", "QC", "KC", "AC",
    "2D", "3D", "4D", "5D", "6D", "7D", "8D", "9D", "TD", "JD", "QD", "KD", "AD",
    "2H", "3H", "4H", "5H", "6H", "7H", "8H", "9H", "TH", "JH", "QH", "KH", "AH",
    "2S", "3S", "4S", "5S", "6S", "7S", "8S", "9S", "TS", "JS", "QS", "KS", "AS"
};

int main()
{
    // seed rng
    srand((unsigned)time(nullptr));
    vector<string> deck(begin(CARDS), end(CARDS));
    random_shuffle(deck.begin(), deck.end());
    copy(deck.begin(), deck.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout," "));
    cout << endl;
};
```

**Output**

```
3S 9C 4C 4S 3H 8D TC 7H TD 5S 3D QC QD 5H TS 4H 3C 7C 9D 6C TH 6S 9S 7S KS KC JC 7D JH 5C 8C 2H JD 9H QS AD JS 2C 4D 6D 8H 5D AS KD 2S 8S AH 6H AC QH 2D KH
```

Comment: Nevermind, posted an error but I fixed it by removing a header that wasn't being used.

Comment: @AndrewB completely different issue than your original question. I would suggest a full clean and dull rebuild of your solution (and I hope you're using at least VS2010 as it will be required to compile the second example).

Comment: Yeah I edited my comment, the problem was caused by a header file that wasn't being used. However now it's complaining about `'time'`, saying the identifier wasn't found

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time) will help. I was missing `#include <ctime>` in the source.

Comment: Evidently putting that in causes the linker error once again, until I take out `#include <algorithm>` and then random_shuffle's identifier isn't found. Oh boy, lovin the errors.

Comment: @AndrewB You're build tool chain needs serious help. Sorry about that.

Comment: I'm not actually using visual studio for compiling these projects, it's all through command prompt and editing in an editor, at this very moment I'm using notepad++, however on my school computer I use UltraEdit. Could this make a difference at all? I have Visual Studio 2012 installed on this PC, and 2010 at school.

Comment: I've actually fixed the problem now, it's because the file being called in my nmake wasn't being used so it was having problems. After removing it from the nmake everything works perfectly, now I just need to implement one feature for aesthetics. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Instead of writing the for-loop to copy the elements from the array to the vector, you can just do this:  `std::vector<const string*> deck(CARDS, CARDS + DECK_SIZE);`

Comment: @ZacHowland That won't work (unless sometime while I wasn't looking the added a `const std::string*` operator to a `std::string`). That constructor takes two iterators *and will dereference them via forward-scan during construction*.

Comment: @WhozCraig:  Ah, I missed that he didn't declare his array as `std::string* CARDS[]` ... Do'h!

Answer (score 1):

This must be an assignment as 3 other people seem to be doing the same thing.

You don't need your card listing to be a `std::string[]`.  You can use `std::array` which will give you the standard STL iterator methods while still being a simple array.  Either way, you can load them into a vector using the `std::vector`'s iterator constructor:

```
// assuming data is loading into myarray and myarray_size is the size of the array
std::vector<std::string> cards(myarray, myarray + myarray_size);
```

You can access the vector's data directly (if needed) by using `&cards[0]` which will give you a pointer to the first element in the array.

That said, if you use the STL templates, you will improve your code and learn the language much more efficiently.

Comment: Okay, so `CARDS` is the array, and I'll just call my vector `cardvec` for now.

So that line of code would be:
`std::vector cardvec(&(CARDS[0]), &(CARDS[CARDS_size - 1]));` ?

Now with regard to it being an assignment, it is and it isn't. It's a project within Michael Dawson's C++ Project's book for Programming  with Text-Based Games.

Comment: I simplified the vector initialization.  You can skip the &-operator since it is a simple array and just use the modified version.  Basically what it tells the vector constructor to do is copy the data from the array starting at `CARDS` (which will point to `CARDS[0]`) and stopping after CARDS_SIZE entries into the cardvec.
Or you can just use `std::array` and skip the `std::vector` entirely.

Comment: I have been granted with the wonderous error of 

C2955: 'std::vector' : use of class template requires template argument list.

I used your near exact line, edited it with the appropriate names but that's about it. I have #include <vector> and now I'm just unsure of what the error is

Comment: The STL collection templates are templates, so you need to specify the type.  I modified the pseudo-code example to show that.